# How to count unique data occuring in multiple categorical columns from a pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, group-by

### The Problem:

In a ML based scenario, I am trying to see the occurrence of data from multiple columns in an Inference file versus the files that were provided to me for Training. I need this to be found only for categorical variables, since numerical attributes are scaled.

### The Expectation:

I've got some success in doing the following in Standard SQL query but I wish to move this into PySpark.

The Training file looks something like this:

| A | B | C | Class |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 0.2 | RDK | AAA |
| 10 | 0.2 | RDK | AAA |
| 10 | 0.2 | RDK | AAA |
| 10 | 1.3 | USW | ACA |
| 10 | 1.3 | USW | ACA |
| 10 | 1.3 | USW | ACA |
| 8 | 0.2 | RDK | BBV |
| 8 | 0.1 | RDJ | BBR |
| 10 | 0.2 | RDK | AAA |
| 10 | 5.1 | RDK | AAA |
| 8 | 0.1 | RDJ | BBR |
| 8 | 0.1 | RDJ | BBR |
| 10 | 5.1 | RDK | AAA |
| 10 | 5.1 | RDK | AAA |
| 8 | 0.1 | RDJ | BBR |
| 8 | 0.1 | RDJ | BBR |

and using sql I am able to get the desired output. However notice that I am matching only Col A and C since they are categorical in nature:

```
select a.A, a.B, a.C, b.prediction, a.Class count(1) as distr_count from train_file a left outer join test_file b 
on a.A = b.A 
and a.C = b.C
group by a.A, a.C
```

**Desired Output:**

| A | B | C | prediction | Class | distr_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 0.2 | RDK | AAA | AAA | 7 |
| 10 | 1.3 | USW | ACA | AAA | 3 |
| 8 | 0.2 | RDK | BBV | BBR | 1 |
| 8 | 0.1 | RDJ | BBR | BBR | 5 |
| 10 | 5.1 | RDK | AAA | AAA | 7 |
| 7 | 1.2 | SSW | BBR | XXX | 0 |

Comment: Your query should be rejected by the compiler because `B` and `class` are in the `SELECT` but not the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ya, that is possible since I've tried to minimize my actual data and query to minimum for understanding. Please update as you feel right, meanwhile I will update the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = train_file.join(test_file, on=['A', 'C'], how='left_outer')
group_df = df.groupBy(['A', 'C']).agg(f.count('class'))
```

Comment: the count() cannot take any parameters. Note: I need this in PySpark.

Comment: Ferraira , Hey man, that .count() was the one that worked for me, apparently both worked out but I'm sticking to ".count()", instead of ".agg()" method.